# Map View in Android

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have tried to use mapView to show map. But, when i run my application it just crash.

When I open the application it crash and nothing is showing.

Map view is not showing instead

My MainActivity source code

```
private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // *** IMPORTANT ***
    // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
    // objects or sub-Bundles.
    Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    }

    mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapViewBundle == null) {
        mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
    }

    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
}
```

Here is my error logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):6)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):20)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):2)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):18)
    at ch.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215028@20.12.15 (020304-0):4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
    at crx.a(:com.google.android.gms@201215007@20.12.15 (020304-302916295):2)
    at afiu.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@201215007@20.12.15 (020304-302916295):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@201215007@20.12.15 (020304-302916295):3)
    at afiv.a(:com.google.android.gms@201215007@20.12.15 (020304-302916295):18)
    at cry.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@201215007@20.12.15 (020304-302916295):12)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:385)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.istiak.locationlatitudelongitude.MainActivity.initGoogleMap(MainActivity.java:91)
    at com.istiak.locationlatitudelongitude.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6156)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2610)
```

library

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that
>    is in the  element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Specify the Google Play services version number
>
> Add the following declaration within the **application** element of
>   **AndroidManifest.xml**. This embeds the version of Google Play services
>   that the app was compiled with.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config

Answer (score 0):

First of all please navigate to this link [Get Your API Key](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) 
Then go to the console and click on the Navigation menu then Api & Services and go to credentials. After that click on create credentials so it automatically creates one API Key. One Popup will come please click on cancel if you don't want to restrict API key. Please don't forget to Enable Maps SDK for Android from the library section of the API & Service menu.
After Getting Api Key please paste it in below code and add this code as mentioned below

```
<application>
...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="your API key"/>
...
</application>
```